# Filetracker: error FTK1011

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

When I try to compile project under framework 4, I get error:

> Filetracker: error FTK1011

Under 3.5 everything works fine, on the other machine, compiling this project under 4 is also works.
And this problem I have only with one project, other projects I can compile under 4 without errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question the same as [this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564511/error-ftk1011-during-build-if-vs2010-project-doesnt-target-net-4?wa=wsignin1.0)?  If so, it looks like the fix will come in an update.  Do you have non-ascii characters in your build paths, perhaps?  That issue references [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/461282/mspdbsrv-exe-logging-does-not-support-unicode-paths).

Comment: 12 years later... All links are broken. I'm getting this error using Emscripten.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has to do with simultaneous project builds. For each project, go to properties, Cofiguration Properties\General and set Intermediate directory to a unique name by substituting $(ProjectDir) for $(SolutionDir). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error appeared when I converted the project of `Visual Studio 2008/2009` version to `Visual Studio 2010` under *`Windows Seven`*.

Solution that helped me: [`change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) .NET framework version to `4.0` in the converted project, by default version was 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred during cmd line builds and was fixed when I modified "arm64" platform entries to "ARM64" in the vcxproj (note the upper case) that gave this error.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case Same Problem when I am changing Debug mode to Release.

I resolve this error by

1. CMakeSettings.json file.

   "name": "x64-Release",

   "configurationType": "Release",
2. CppProperties.json File.

   "name": "x64-Release",

Thanks,

ANR .S